# How to Make it Responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

My question is simple, i have an **e-commerce website and i would like to make it responsive** (desktop, tablet and mobile), what should i do to achieve that, is it enough to use a responsive framework, and rewrite my css ? i'm trying to choose between Bootstrap and Foundation, i have a small experience with front-end development, i would like to know **what is the fastest way** to achieve that, **which framework** is better, **is there something that i'm missing?**

Thank you, i appreciate your help :)

Comment: Ought to go with `Bootstrap`. its very light-weight and quite popular. Further you dont need to take any paid courses to learn bootstrap. Everything is there with examples at http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Without seeing your code or website there isn't much advice anyone can give you specifically however if I was you I would strip out your custom CSS and install Bootstrap or Foundation then rebuild from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap is made to have everything included to "bootstrap" your project / website. It's meant to include absolutely (well, almost) everything you need to build a website.

Foundation is provided to be the "foundation" of your project / website. It's a little bit more lightweight then Bootstrap (If I remember correctly), and the included CSS is leaning more towards customization.

From personal experience, Bootstrap is easier to learn, it has a bigger community (more resources, tutorials and add-ons), but it can mean that your website will look like all the other "Bootstrapped" sites.

But, no framework is better then the other, they all have their strengths and weaknesses. You just have to choose accordingly (depending on the type of project and your front-end expertise).

Ideally, I would advise you to start from scratch using Bootstrap, slowly adding your own CSS to define the visual style of your e-commerce site.